# How does await/async work?

Tags: multithreading, async-await

Suppose thread A use 'await' to wait for something to finish on thread B. while B is busy with the workload, A is considered to have been marked with a 'suspension point'. And the execution flow in A will continue with the 'caller' method of the suspended code block. When B is done, it will notify A to continue from the suspension point.

My questions are:

- What is the content of the context info kept for the suspension point?
- How is the context info be stored?
- How does B notify A about it's completion?
- How is the context info of A restored? (I think once the context info for A is restored, A will resume from the suspension point 'naturally')
- What's the effect of 'async' and 'await' on compiler, respectively. In other words, what special work does the compiler do behind the curtain.

Answer (score 3):

First, forget threads. `async` and `await` have very little to do with threading and much more to do with rewriting methods so you can use continuation passing style more easily.

I recommend you read my [`async`/`await` intro post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and then follow up with the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) (which is quite good). That would answer all your questions except the last one, which is best answered by [Jon Skeet's eduasync blog series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the referencing materials, due to the time limit, i have only read only a few materials so far. I will spend some time reading the links.